# How to roll R's in russian language

Tags: английский

How to roll/trill the letter R in a russian accent?

Comment: Angela, what is your native language?

Answer (score 3):

This [manual](http://www.wikihow.com/Roll-Your-%22R%22s) looks pretty elaborate. Good luck!

(I can't do it, by the way...)

Comment: Very nice manual. Interesting note: My toddler kids can make rolling R sound in the tractor noise, i.e. when asked what noise the tractors do they say very good TTTRRRRRRR. Therefore I teach them using the TR/DR method (#2 in the manual). I find it quite successful

Comment: Funny :)
I’m Russian, and we actually used the word “tractor” when taught our daughters to do it :)

We used a small silly poem:

Трактор в поле «Тыр-Тыр-Тыр»,
Я в колхозе бригадир

Answer (score 2):

Russian r's are formed by flapping the tip of your tongue against the alveolar ridge (behind  your upper teeth)--you only need to flap once or twice. A good way to learn how to do this is to say the word рука only give a really strong puff of air as you say the р. In your question you mention a Russian accent. That normally implies the way some other language is pronounced as a Russian might pronounce it, for example, as a Russian might pronounce English words (with a Russian accent). The trilling of the r in this case would be the same if you want to pronounce English words with a Russian accent.

Comment: Against the back of your teeth??? Are you kidding? Russian /r/ is [post-alveolar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology#Consonants), there's a huge way to the teeth when you pronounce the Russian /r/.

Comment: Right--thanks for pointing that out. Edit made.